# Copy Constructor invoked instead of assignment operator

Tags: c++

Consider the following self contained Code.

```
#include <iostream>
template<typename Ty>
class Foo {
private:
    Ty m_data;
public:
    Foo() :m_data() {}
    Foo(Ty data) :m_data(data) {}
    template<typename U>
    Foo& operator=(Foo<U> rv)
    {
        m_data = rv.m_data;
        return *this;
    }
private:
    Foo(Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(Foo&);
};
int main()
{
    Foo<int> na(10);
    Foo<int> nb;
    nb = Foo<int>(10); // (1)
    Foo<int>(10); // (2)
}
```

My understanding is statement (1) is an assignment rather than a Copy COnstructor. Yet, when compiling (VC++ and G++), the Error Message states, it tries to match a Copy Constructor which was declared private.

```
1>Source.cpp(23): error C2248: 'Foo<int>::Foo' : cannot access private member declared in class 'Foo<int>'
1>          Source.cpp(16) : see declaration of 'Foo<int>::Foo'
```

My question is, why does it try to search for a Copy Constructor instead of an assignment.

**Note**, I know it is the assignment that is failing because (2) compiles fine without any error.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There are *two* issues:

1. Your private assignment operator `Foo& operator=(Foo&);` takes a non-const lvalue reference. That means it cannot be selected as an overload in `nb = Foo<int>(10);`, because the RHS is an rvalue
2. That leads to your template assignment operator being selected. But that takes its argument by value, requiring a copy or move copy constructor.

If you fix 1. to take a `const` reference, gcc gives the following error:

> error: 'Foo& Foo::operator=(const Foo&) [with Ty = int]' is private

If you fix 2. so that the template assignment operator takes a `const` reference, the code compiles without errors.

Comment: MSVC has an extension to allow non-const lvalue reference to take a temporary, so I'm curious as to why that extension is not being applied in this code

Comment: @MattMcNabb MSVC often gets templates wrong, so it could be failing for other reasons. But the code could also have been compiled without extensions.

Comment: OK, I didn't realize it was possible to turn that extension off.

Answer (score 4):

Your assignment operator takes its parameter by value, which requires making a copy. That copy may (or may not) be elided - but the copy constructor still needs to be available and accessible, even if not called.

Answer (score 0):

Your assignment operator passes argument by value, so it uses copy ctor:

```
template<typename U>
Foo& operator=(Foo<U> rv)
```

Possible solution to pass it by const refernce:

```
template<typename U>
Foo& operator=(const Foo<U> &rv)
```

Answer (score -1):

A private version

```
private:
    Foo(Foo&);
    Foo& operator=(Foo&);
```

cannot be called because it takes non-const lvalue reference so

```
Foo& operator=(Foo<U> rv)
```

this version is called but it takes parameter *by value* and copy constructor has to be invoked.

Comment: DOWNVOTER please care to explain / review